# Gulp watch, wait for task

Tags: javascript, msbuild, gulp, browser-sync

I'd like to watch multiple files, when they change I'd like to run MsBuild and fire a reload with BrowserSync when the build is finished. So far I've got this "watcher":

```
gulp.watch([config.templatePath+'/**/*','!'+config.templatePath+'/assets/stylesheets/**/*'],['build']).on('change', function(file) {
    browsersync.reload(file);
});
```

And this build task:

```
gulp.task('build', function() {
    return gulp
        .src(config.projectFile)
        .pipe(msbuild({
            toolsVersion: 12.0
        }));
});
```

This is working fine, but the browser is reloaded before the build is finished. First I thought is was a problem with gulp-msbuild but I was forgotten the `return`, see: https://github.com/hoffi/gulp-msbuild/issues/8.

The build task is fired before the reload, but it's not waiting until it's completed. Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you'll need a separate task for that, like `build_reload`:

```
gulp.task('build_reload', function() {
    return gulp
        .src(config.projectFile)
        .pipe(msbuild({
            toolsVersion: 12.0
        }))
        .on('end', function() {
            browsersync.reload();
        }));;
});
```

then change the `watch` task to:

```
gulp.watch([config.templatePath + '/**/*', '!' + config.templatePath + '/assets/stylesheets/**/*'], ['build_reload']);
```

this way it's only going to reload after everything finished.

Comment: or .on('end', browsersync.reload)